# Two ros root defined in config

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm the following problem.

(Over-)Writing setup.sh, setup.bash, and setup.zsh in /home/iohan/ros
ERROR in rosinstall: Two ros roots defined in config, delete one: /home/iohan/ros/ros /opt/ros/fuerte/share/rosiohan@administrador:~$

Two ros root, how to solve?
help, help,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42687/two-ros-root-defined-in-config/) by [Iohan Goncalves](https://answers.ros.org/users/3113/iohan-goncalves/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Iohan Goncalves](https://answers.ros.org/users/3113/iohan-goncalves/) on 2012-08-30**:
I'm from Brazil....rsrs

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-30**:
Where do you define $ROS_ROOT? Please edit your question and add the relevant contents of your .bashrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your setup.sh tries to set ROS_ROOT for you based on all entries in your .rosinstall file. It looks for any entry in your .rosinstall which is a stack with the name 'ros'.

So in your .rosinstall, there are two entries fulfilling that condition, and you need to remove one of those from your .rosinstall.

Which one of these entries you have to remove is up to you. If you explain why you have a 'ros' stack in  /home/iohan/ros/ros we can help more.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also see:

http://answers.ros.org/question/30446/error-in-rosinstall-two-ros-roots-defined-in-config/

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1